# Is SQLite encryption backwards compatible?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

I have a project that uses encrypted SQLite databases for file storage. It references a dll called System.Data.SQLite.dll

Here are the file properties

[image]

I'm not sure where the dll came from, I inherited the project. I think it may be a third party encryption wrapper for the standard SQLite.

Anyway, I want to upgrade to the latest version of SQLite from Nuget, but so far I can't open the data files because they are encrypted. It looks like the latest versions of SQLite has encryption built in, and I've tried putting the encryption password in the connection string, but that didn't work.

I need to know whether the current built-in encryption is backwards compatible with my dll, and if it is then what do I need to change in my code to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an ecryption wrapper but:

> System.Data.SQLite is an ADO.NET provider for SQLite.

[System.Data.SQLite](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki)

I suggest you download the [Documentation for System.Data.SQLite](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/Doc/SQLite.NET.chm?mimetype=application/x-chm) and look at the

> Introduction to System.Data.SQLite > Version History

section to find out whether any of the changes might have broken your code.